# Postgres partition search in reverse order of partitions

Tags: partitioning, postgresql-9.6

Our production system is on postgres 9, with a partition table. In one of the select queries, we cannot pass the partition key for the select, but we want the data from the latest partition, is it possible to make the postgres search from the last partition backwards?

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM user.user
WHERE username = 123456
ORDER BY start_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This searches from the earliest partition to the most recently created partition even though I've ordered my partition key in descending order. Is there a way to make postgres look from the recent most partition and look backward?

DDL of table:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS user.user
(
    id                      uuid      default journey.uuid_generate_v4() not null,
    username                varchar(255),
    email_id                varchar(255),
    start_time              timestamp not null,
    end_time                timestamp not null
);


create table if not exists user.user_201301  
(CHECK ( start_time >= DATE '2013-01-01' AND start_time < DATE '2013-02-01')) INHERITS (user.user);
ALTER TABLE if exists user.user_201301 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
....
```

We've partition tables until 202101 and will continue.

On the above select query, the explain looks at all the partitions from 201301 till 202101, how do I make it look from 202101 backwards to 201301, this will make my query easier.

Comment: Please provide information — preferably in the form of DDL — about how you have setup the partitions. Is there any reason you haven’t upgraded to Postgres 12? You’re 3 major versions behind now.

Comment: @Colin'tHart updated the DDL. With respect to update, we are on AWS RDS Aurora with postgres as the engine with cloudformation as a way to build our DB, the cloudformation template has a problem, if we change the engine version, AWS does a replacement of the RDS which replaces the DB and essentially wiping out data and snapshots, we're working with AWS on a workaround , currently there's no workaround and we've to stick with postgres 9.6 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-engineversion

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: `partition by RANGE` is not valid in [9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createtable.html) ?

Comment: @Luuk sorry, I posted my DDL with another DB from postgres 10, 
````PARTITION BY RANGE```` is in postgres 10 and not in 9.6, I've edited my question

Comment: Can you explain why a query will become easier? ("On the above select query, the explain looks at all the partitions from 201301 till 202101, how do I make it look from 202101 backwards to 201301, this will make my query easier.")

Comment: @Luuk The search key that I have is indexed, the application is complicated that I can't have the start_time in the select clause. I also know 99% of my queries are in the most recent partition and there's a very high chance the others would be in the previous year. However, there's a very small chance that it could be earlier, if my query is from the last partition and backwards, my query response would be faster rather than the other way round -- where postgres has to check indexes of all partitions from the beginning to now.

Comment: But your query HAS to check the user_201301 partition before it can return results, so there should be not much gain if this is done at start, or at the end...

Comment: I know most of my users are created recently, hence if the check goes from the last partition back, the query response is faster. 99% of my scenario is like that